# Equivalent of `loadViewIfNeeded` for cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I'm looking for equivalent function on AppKit for UIKit's `loadViewIfNeeded`. (this is in order to populate outlets programmatically).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reference the view on the `NSViewController`. Since you didn't specify the language, I'll give the answer in both Objective-C:

```
(void)viewController.view;
```

and Swift:

```
_ = viewController.view
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply query the `view` property on `NSViewController`.

In other words, the equivalent implementation is just:

```
// Swift
func loadViewIfNeeded() {
    _ = self.view
}
// Obj-C
- (void)loadViewIfNeeded {
   (void)self.view;
}
```

I don't recommend making this added abstraction, as this is a Cocoa convention that is understood. In my mind, if you're trying to force load the view, it usually is a code smell. Your view should be able to render itself based on the model representing it.

Comment: I know the OP didn't specify the language, dude, but whichever language s/he's using, I'm pretty sure it's not "mishmash of Swift func declaration and Objective-C function body." :-P

Comment: Haha, I use Obj-C so much that I'm blending my thoughts.

Comment: I didn't understand. Do you recommend _not_ doing this? if so, why?

Comment: @gerbil He edited the answer and fixed it. The original code snippet he provided was half Swift and half Obj-C, and wouldn't have compiled in either. :-P

Comment: @gerbil I was advocating not to create a method called `loadViewIfNeeded`. I was just saying if you were to implement one, this would be the equivalent. I would try to avoid requiring the view loading to happen for initializing your view controller. Try to keep your model as a distinct value that represents your view regardless of whether the view is loaded or not.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh I need to bind the view to the viewModel. That’s why I’m doing it. (And I don’t want to call it from viewDidLoad)

Answer (score 0):

`NSViewController` has private method named `-[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired]`, maybe equivalent of `loadViewIfNeeded`.